# Project references working in a small team in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio

I do most of work and I love to add project references to my main project. These sub projects are live and I edit the code often, so having project references in the main project helps me to navigate for the code and compiling it quickly. Another value is the automatic selection of release/debug assembly.

Now I need to work with few external workers. I use Git for source control. These workers need to work on the main project, not on satellite projects. If I leave the project references to the main project, I would need to share the code of these projects. I want to avoid it because workers never need to change or see the sub-project source.

In the other hand, if I replace the project references by simply references, I will lose the ability to navigate and edit the source of sub projects from the main project.

Which would be a good practice for working on the above scenario?

Comment: Change the references to DLL file of your sub-projects and push this state of your project to git, and then change your references to the projects. Every time you changed your sub-projects push the DLLs too. In this case you shouldn't push your project file.

Comment: Also you can change the output path of your projects to common path and after your changes on project(s) push their output on git.

Comment: *I want to avoid it because workers never need to change or see the sub-project source* that makes no sense, it just puts a burden on them. E.g what if they want to step through the code becasue the found a bug? Why would you not want your collegues to see your code?? You're a *team*, right? Anyway if you want to prohibit changes, which is sort of understandable, host your repositories with gitolite or similar, so you can set premissions for who can and cannot modify. That's a good idea anyway: if you're the lead, you don't want other to push directly to the master branch.

Comment: stijn,
No, they are not my team. They are external developers not related with my company. We do not want to share the source of all projects, only the source of the project that we hired them for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days, I have found the solution at http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/conditional-project-or-library-reference-in-visual-studio/#comment-3597